# How do I fix this error: Result cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I typed up this java program calculating simple interest in Eclipse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PercentageCalculator 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new
            Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value of x: ");
    x = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the value of y: ");
    y = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Calculating percentage: (x % of y): ");

    System.out.println(x + " % of" + y + "is " + result);
    System.out.println(); 
}

}
```

But when I tried to run it, it gave me this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
result cannot be resolved to a variable

at PercentageCalculator.main(PercentageCalculator.java:19)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: you need to declare it and you didn't use it and use google first

Comment: Yes `result cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: You forgot to define, calculate and assign the **result** to *`result`*.

Answer (score 2):

Declare you result variable

```
double result = 0;
```

then calculate the percentage and assign it to your result variable.

```
result = your calculation;
```

then print it

```
System.out.println(x + " % of" + y + "is " + result);
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not declare the result variable

```
double result=0;
```

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.